# How to make this django attribute name search better?

Tags: django

```
lcount = Open_Layers.objects.all()
form = SearchForm()

if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = SearchForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        val=form.cleaned_data['LayerName']

        a=Open_Layers()
        data = []
        for e in lcount:
            if e.Layer_name == val:     
                data = val 

        return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'data':data})

    else:
        form = SearchForm()

 else:
    return render_to_response('mapsearch.html', {'form':form})
```

This just returns back if a particular "name" matches . How do to change it so that it returns when I give a search for "Park" , it should return Park1 , Park2 , Parking , Parkin i.e all the occurences of the park .

Comment: Now you're just guessing. That's not how programming works.

Comment: Two separate questions here. Please edit and make the second one a separate post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436912/in-django-how-to-make-a-link-out-of-a-search-value-returned Have made another question out of this here .

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your searching logic by using a `list` to accumulate the results and the `re` module to match a larger set of words.

However, this is still pretty limited, error prone and hard to maintain or even harder to make evolve. Plus you'll never get as nice results as if you were using a search engine.

So instead of trying to manually reinvent the wheel, the car and the highway, you should spend some time setting up [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). This is now the *de facto* standard to do search in Django.

Use `woosh` as a backend at first, it's going to be easier. If your search get slow, replace it with `solr`.

EDIT:

Simple clean alternative:

```
Open_Layers.objects.filter(name__icontains=val)
```

This will perform a SQL `LIKE`, adding %` for you.

This going to kill your database if used too often, but I guess this is probably not going to be an issue with your current project.

BTW, you probably want to rename `Open_Layers` to `OpenLayers` as this is the Python PEP8 naming convention.

Comment: I already installed it . But , I dont need such an extensible search .

Comment: I got the haystack up and running . It seems to be too much for the small project I have now , But I am sure it will come into use . Any clue what does django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer used & can be removed.
 mean ? My settings are configured exactly the way it is mentioned in Haystack

Comment: I think it means that the HAYSTACK_SITECONF setting is no longer user & can be removed

Comment: @e-satis I tried your procedure . It is truncating the result . So I am going to use Haystack . But stuck with its configuration . Some days django is so easy. some days it frustrates you to bits . This is my settings.py http://dpaste.com/557350/

Comment: For you haystack question, create a new question, otherwise it's going to get messy. For the second part, since your are not telling us any of the error you get (what the hell truncating means ?), I'll pass and let others SO user try to read your mind. Espacially since you didn't even upvoted two people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if e.Layer_name == val:     
   data = val
```

use

```
if val in e.Layer_name:     
   data.append(e.Layer_name)
```

(and you don't need the line `data = form.cleaned_data`)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post, but anyway:

There's a fuzzy logic string comparison already in the python standard library.

```
import difflib
```

Mainly have a look at:

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a='string1', b='string2', autojunk=True).ratio()
```

more info here:
http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects

What it does it returns a ratio of how close the two strings are, between zero and 1. So instead of testing if they're equal, you chose your similarity ratio.

Things to watch out for, you may want to convert both strings to lower case.

```
string1.lower()
```

Also note you may want to impliment your favourite method of splitting the string i.e. .split() or something using re so that a search for 'David' against 'David Brent' ranks higher.