# In django , how to make a link out of a search value returned?

Tags: django

This is the inital question and I had asked , as there were 2 questions in it , I thought I will make another question from it .

[How to make this django attribute name search better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435661/how-to-make-this-django-attribute-name-search-better) .

The second question there was , once a search value is returned to searchresult.html . How do I make link out of it , that would link directly to the search data .

if the result returned is "Park" , which is a name of the file , How do I make it link , which I can link to another view that shows the contents of the data ?

Comment: You want to use the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag.

Answer (score 0):

I read your first question. I will give you an idea.

1. In your search results template, you have a dictionary named data. With that, you can get the ID of the object in the search results. Create a hyperlink with that ID.
   ex:

   ```
   <a href='/view-details/{{ data.id }}'>{{ data }}</a>
   ```
2. Make a function in your views that gets the detail of an Object using it's ID. (It's parameter should require an ID.)
3. Create a template for that view.
4. Map the function and the url in the urls.py of your app. For example:

   url(r'^view-details/(?P)/$', 'view_details', name='details'),